# Right place to place injects attribute in dagger plus'ed modules

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger

I have a doubt regarding which is the right place to set the injects attribute (not annotation) in dagger, when there are plus'ed graphs.

We have this scenario:

```
@Module(injects = ClassWithInjects.class, complete = false)
public final class BaseModule {

  @Provides
  DependencyA providesA() { return new A(); }
  @Provides
  DependencyB providesB() { return new B(); }
  ...
}

class ClassWithInjects {
  @Inject
  A a;
  @Inject
  B b;
}
```

that was working fine when doing:

```
ObjectGraph graph = ObjectGraph.create(new BaseModule()).plus(new Object[0]); // no modules used to plus by default
graph.inject(new ClassWithInjects());
```

Afterwards we added a new module that is the only one supposed to provide B from that moment on:

```
@Module(injects = ClassWithInjects.class, complete = false)
public final class BaseModule {

  @Provides
  DependencyA providesA() { return new A(); }
  ...
}

@Module(addsTo = BaseModule.class, complete = false)
public final class AdditionalModule {
  @Provides
  DependencyB providesB() { return new B(); }
}

class ClassWithInjects {
  @Inject
  A a;
  @Inject
  B b;
}
```

That is failing with

> IllegalStateException No binding for B required by class
>   ClassWithInjects

when doing this:

```
ObjectGraph graph = ObjectGraph.create(new BaseModule()).plus(new AdditionalModule());
graph.inject(new ClassWithInjects());
```

It works when I move the

> injects = ClassWithInjects.class

attribute from BaseModule to AdditionalModule.

So, where am I supposed to place the injects attribute when using plus'ed modules? Does it have to be in one of the modules used as parameters in the call to .plus(...)?

According to [this github issue](https://github.com/square/dagger/issues/228) I have to put the injects in the module that has the bindings for the instance I try to inject dependencies into (ClassWithInjects in the example above) but, what if I have several modules providing the different bindings needed to fulfill all the dependencies of that instance? Do I have to create a module that includes all the others and put there the injects attribute?

Comment: The AdditionalModule should be complete in the state you present, since B doesn't depend on A.

Comment: Yes @DandreAllison it's a stripped down version of the actual code, which has more providers that require the module to be not-complete. Nevertheless that is not related to my question about the placement of injects, right?

Comment: That's why I put it in a comment. Another thing, have you considered the "includes" field? It lets you concatenate separate modules, when you create an `ObjectGraph` with a module that has "includes" then all transitively included modules (de-dublicated) get added to the `ObjectGraph`.

Comment: Yes, I have in the last paragraph of the question: having a module with that includes others that is used to place the injects attribute.  I'm testing that scenario but wanted feedback for better, if any, alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the Android sample here: https://github.com/square/dagger/tree/master/examples/android-activity-graphs/src/main/java/com/example/dagger/activitygraphs

Comparing that setup to what you have, the "injects" were defined on the Module that was plussed. I think a current limitation is that you have to define those on every plussed Module in the case where you have multiple.